# Max/MSP JavaScript distortion possible?

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, max-msp-jitter, msi-patch

I'm trying to help a friend to figure out if it's possible to implement DSP algorithms in Max/MSP javascript. He was told so in class, and he asked for my help but I can't find any way to process actual samples.

TL;DR
Is it possible to get samples in and return them out in Max/MSP using javascript?
Thanks

Comment: What you want is the Eric Lyon book on doing this in C, it's great!

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not, as it's made only for processing messages and not signal vectors. Probably you mixed JavaScript with Java — there is a `mxj~` object which allows you to use Java 6 (not higher!) for developing signal processing algorithms. Check out the tutorial, which everyone starts to learn how to use Java with: http://pcm.peabody.jhu.edu/~gwright/stdmp/docs/WritingMaxExternalsInJava.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can write DSP algorithms using Max’s `gen~` and `codebox`, the syntax for which resembles JavaScript or C.

DSP in Max runs at high priority to avoid audio dropouts, which the `js` object does not, but it is possible to generate code using JavaScript and load that into a `gen~` instance. You can find an example of this bundled with Max itself: search for a file called `gen~.dynamicexpr.maxpat`

Answer (score 0):

They released a node.js API with Max 8. You can now.

Answer (score 0):

Though not using javascript, like delucis said you can now use `gen~` to write dsp code.

Here's a distortion `gen~` function using `tanh` for my own project:

```
    tanh_dist(input, amp, offset)
    {
        pass1 = input + offset;
        pass2 = pass1 * amp;
        pass3 = tanh(pass2);
        return(dcblock(pass3));
    }
```

I also made a sample patch to show you how to use it (in the codebox). Just copy the following text and paste into an empty max patch window:

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
1168.3ocyW8tbiZCD+y3mBF9TROWOHAXG2qsyzGf9Db4FOxfLVWAACH74bYx
8r2U+ALXv13j3zlOPFu+jzt6uc0tZedhky5r8zRG6ey9K1VVOOwxRIRJvx7a
KmTx9vDRoZYNgYooTtvYpFSP2KTxy1rojJdjWCjSDgaY73UEzPgVA3kAybmZ
iWH+hBbk+yyelq8WM6gWkx3ITgRSnCBypD0RcMRYQZst9a+Jx0QJ6kISjel9
F8CRZ94cBWzAmve9rf2EeX9qwE1jjAGbsstIqHknLx4FIfgvRgEHU4rZkBmv
AgnKFrl6K+piUX704m3994xCLaAIkJnEqnbx5DZadQeDhmxoZSwwYpsyZBO1
w9q2ZZJnOMgOPdCvSnkKj4.uy7zh+C3IN86fp6cgH7ovD5OsQv0ryvBttGxV
lGbdV.OHKf5yBANmxSKYwbRxqyOiIL9Ouru3gvp5TK0+J3RwzzpDAKbKgyoI
6HELBWzNXcwPt+qJjaHBHv+5HC5OhHgifM7cWp9WP82qIzNPAOry6WFZLcLw
SLVEOwH+ymc5M1rSzkyNaaTzBimYbMnTDKgtiVTxx3sTgkCIOukXqVaQxGeK
ScPOLsQDiqE41HpftiUueuFojBfZD.uTUnrTm8yqS5jGSVDsfWwTlhVHDYLl
jJFvgzxxbRndyQk4y.lu9.bZ2hbt5lybcgf4lLHYwwZJAhzwIYg+CMpsg6jk
S4LddAsDZMSDFOnANhtg.2xVsIiKJY+PYGpaoCfuwXmCBJ8DkS7Wv8zjFWHt
fEkwkFQm3gTbs5fzo.8yWZ6LpUvI4CrYHSAHlS.VBNYU4ZRgLbYtpiqAEYYI
cgZ1WBciv.myfBNcYQQV9oAKXwaOydWmAfom6rUHkqp3ZzUPlgXUIYWW1VPR
RLWW6d76IP2VhfJX5P.1sATWtaaYXQVRRG+Uira.jHHSOj9cVjXam24HQfky
xqShbZhxQrXZonqLAItrqjRwSZRuknp0laxqDzz7DvK5tfNOlt8011E15H+b
E35Vjiws8ZCLPgNeSGKcAtGNtLW+RctcA5Wt6TMjOwyOzcfrpKraJgbS3BzE
3B8KwtgTA5+MTA9BTA1Cci4B7GHWDBsojqrkF6TQ+2+anNqpKUzeNtbDrhX7
dPOWmbvtSSMdGo1i6xLZJy6RT1QJZf1cp9x.anNSAgucUDqTbGz+rRL0Flic
psdn76ej+7iba3ubfEQ1+gsZM1exf+4CfX.TuneQdBsP7.DoRtSsr6MHET3w
D76hBWK6lqv7tWB9xiEOxA+BY1VssglBJGK+3c+mc9Xti.lwEqWfVndyhO5g
5W6eoaInSFxcGNj6Oj6d3MDIL9oZdnrWI9v7PYVUQXcpioLscWKGZFJX7lWT
8kljPa7Hucds1f2HsAe85tI1.9J3AzMxFPWgMLLOXDpkXlXRcfcSYzCPcr4Y
FipmYsrsYcBSBcH8n2fZiUOKFodPuQ8DLR839F0i+HzSmzNmrhH8nenODEi5
qX22jhQiPw98XVcB5QSxJUwQSvdzzq8mb8zSsd7DqpoUGZRUYCjIuL4eArSi
FpB
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```